# JDBC - java can't see installed drivers

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have a problem with JDBC drivers. I can't connect with my SQL Server database. Following code for test:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

       Connection con = null;
       String conUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName=mydb; user=root; password=psswd;";

   try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl);
    System.out.println("OK");
  } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
         finally {
           if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
         }
}}
```

When i try run this code i still getting error:

```
java.sql.sqlexception no suitable driver found for (..)
```

I have added path to sqljdbc4.jar to classpath variable and enu\auth\x64 localization to Path variable. I'm working on JRE 1.8, SQL Server 2014 and Windows 7.

Comment: add them to classpath please

Comment: what IDE you are using, how you added the driver to path?

Comment: How do you run your code? Also: the global `classpath` variable is deprecated and should not be used. You should specify the classpath when starting your application `java -cp sqljdbc4.jar;yourapp.jar Test`

Comment: This code is only for test. I'm using JDBC in other other applications (Pentaho Data Integration, scriptella etc.), but they reporting the same error like in my code. It is not this application problem, this is problem with drivers

Comment: How do you execute this? Show the commandline you use. Also, consider removing the whitespace after the `;`, because AFAIK the parser of the Microsoft JDBC driver does not support/allow spaces there

Answer (score -1):

It's because you haven't loaded the driver. Just modify your existing code

```
try {
 //this will load the driver
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection(conUrl);
System.out.println("OK");
 } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
     finally {
       if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
 }
```

Comment: This is not necessary if you have a newer JDBC driver (one that supports JDBC 4.0). I don't know if the MS SQL Server driver that OP is using is a JDBC 4.0 driver.

Comment: This hasn't been necessary (except for web applications with the driver in the context) since 2006.

Comment: @Mark Web applications usually use JNDI so they would get a connection from a DataSource (no need for Class.forName). Also, the class loader will not always load the driver even when it's a type 4 driver so explicitly calling Class.forName may help.

Comment: In my experience a lot of web applications don't bother with JNDI, nor server level data sources at all. The behavior of DriverManager is predictable: it will automatically load drivers on the initial classpath, not on a context classpath.

Comment: The Oracle docs says that using JNDI is the recommended way to obtain a db connection for web applications. Of course, many web apps developers probably don't care. Anyway, lets leave it at that.